# Django Rest Framework: How to get instance of related foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**Note:** IF INFORMATION BELOW IS NOT CLEAR TO UNDERSTAND - PLEASE ASK ME, I WILL UPDATE AND POST INFORMATION YOU NEED | It is important for me

---

In `Warehouse(models.Model)` I have `amount` attribute and

in `ChosenProduct(models.Model)` - `quantity`

I'm trying to get `amount` in `Warehouse` through `chosen_products` *instance* in `App_formSerializer` to add the quantity of *chosen_product*

But I can not get the `chosen_products` objects from `instance`
--> below **Out:**

```
class WarehouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='category_product.category_name')
    posted_user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='posted_user.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Warehouse
        fields = ['id', 'category_product', 'category_name', 'condition',
                  'product_name', 'amount', 'barcode', 'f_price', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'posted_user']

class ChosenProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_info = WarehouseSerializer(source='product', read_only=True)
    period_info = Product_periodSerializer(source='period', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ChosenProduct
        exclude = ('app_form',)

class App_formSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chosen_products = ChosenProductSerializer(many=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.terminated = validated_data.get('terminated', instance.terminated)
        
        if instance.terminated == True :
              
            print('-----------TRUE--------------------')
            print(instance.chosen_products)
            print('-----------PRINT--------------------')

        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = App_form
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Out**

```
-----------TRUE--------------------
creditapi.ChosenProduct.None
-----------PRINT--------------------
```

---

QUESTION UPDATED

---

**models.py**

```py
    class Warehouse(models.Model):
        category_product = models.ForeignKey(
            Category_product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        condition = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        amount = models.IntegerField()
        barcode = models.BigIntegerField()
        f_price = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        posted_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.product_name
    
    class App_form(models.Model):
        phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,12}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '998981234567'. Up to 12 digits allowed.")
        terminated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=13)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.surname
    
    class ChosenProduct(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        quantity = models.IntegerField()
        app_form = models.ForeignKey(App_form, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chosen_products')
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.product.product_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `instance.chose_products` you access the *manager*, not the `QuerySet` that contains the items. You can use `.all()` to obtain the `QuerySet` with all the objects:

```
print(instance.chosen_products.all())
```

If you access a `ForeignKey` in reverse, you have a manager, since zero, one, or *more* elements can refer to the `instance`.

You can for example aggregate over the `chose_products`, for example if you want to retrieve the number of related `chose_products`, you can use:

```
print(instance.chosen_products.count())
```

I would however advise not store (aggregated) data in the `App_form`, but aggregate data when you need it. Data duplication is an anti-pattern, and it turns out it is hard to keep data in sync.

Comment: And how can I get the 'product_info' object inside the 'chosen_products'?

Comment: @ShukurSharofiddinov: but this is *no* object. There can be multiple `ProjectInfo`s refering to the same instance, so it is a *collection* of objects that can contain zero, one, or more items...

Comment: I should change the value of 'amount' in  'product_info' which is WarehouseSerializer

Comment: @ShukurSharofiddinov: In that case you should make use of annotations: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Comment: Okay, I understand, and finally how can I clear instance.chosen_products ?

Comment: @ShukurSharofiddinov: with `instance.chose_products.clear()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships

Comment: OUT:   AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'clear'

Comment: @ShukurSharofiddinov: what version of Django do you use: as specified in the documentation, Django-3.0 for example, a `RelatedManager` has a `.clear` attribute: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear

Comment: I am using version 3.0.8

Comment: @ShukurSharofiddinov: what is the output of `print(type(instance.chose_products))`? and `django.__version__` (when you import `django`).

Comment: <class 'django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.<locals>.RelatedManager'>

Comment: @ShukurSharofiddinov: ah but the `ForeignKey` is non-nullable. So when you remove it, you want to *delte* the related `chose_products`? Then you can work with `instance.chose_products.all().delete()`